# VS Code has wrong keyboard shortcut layout

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using a US keyboard for coding. But my VS Code installation is using a different shortcut layout. How can I switch to US keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Maybe you can find helpful information here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

EDIT: I wonder why it wouldn't be US as this seems to be the default.

Comment: It seems the shortcut layout is supposed to change with switching the keyboard layout, but if so it's not working. This seems to work fine in Windows 10, but not in Ubuntu which I'm using now.

Comment: Don't know how it works in Ubuntu, but you are sure you have set the system wide keyboard layout settings in Ubuntu to US?

Comment: Now I found this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-linux-keybindings

Seems this is a known problem in Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, turned out this page had the answer:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot-linux-keybindings

Specifically, running

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue as I code with DVORAK keyboard layout and setting `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` in VS Code solved my issue.

Comment: I've had to do this on github.dev, even though "normal" VS Code works fine for me